# Checkers on a Checkerboard

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we place anywhere from $0$ to $9$ indistinguishable checkers on a $3\times 3$ checkerboard (no more than one checker per square), such that no row or column contains exactly $1$ checker?

I know this question has been asked before, but the answer was not complete.

Comment: Well, if you know that the question has been asked before and an incomplete answer was given, wouldn't the obvious thing be to link to that thread so we don't have to duplicate the efforts invested there?

Comment: Here's the link: http://http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996916/constructive-counting-math-problem-about-checkers-on-a-checkerboard

Comment: Here's a link that works: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996916

Comment: Thanks, joriki, for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: @MathMuse: Check the comments under that answer: they add the missing details.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see the button to click for more comments.

Comment: I added [an answer based on inclusion-exclusion](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1887335/6622) to the other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with $n=0$ clearly $1$ way.

with $n=1$ clearly $0$ ways.

with $n=2$ clearly $0$ ways.

with $n=3$ clearly $0$ ways. (if we don't want a row with $1$ checker all must be in the same row)

If $n=4$ then the columns must be $2,2,0$ and the rows must be $2,2,0$. So the tiles must form the corners of a rectangle, there are $3$ ways to choose the top and bottom sides of the rectangle and $3$ ways to choose the left and right sides of the rectangle. So $9$ in total.

If $n=5$ then consider how many per row, it can only be $3,2,0$. And clearly this implies one column has exactly one chip, so zero ways.

If $n=6$ then consider how many per row, it can be $3,3,0$ or $2,2,2$. If it is $3,3,0$ then there are clearly $3$ ways. If it is $2,2,2$ there are two possible arrangements for the columns: $3,3,0$ or $2,2,2$. The first one yields $3$ arrangements and the second $6$ arrangements. In total $12$ ways.

If $n=7$ then the only way it does not work is if the two "missing" squares are in the same row/column, there are clearly $6\times 3=18$ ways to pick the two missing tiles, hence there are $\binom{9}{7}-18=18$ correct arrangements.

If $n=8$ clearly every way works, so $9$.

If $n=9$ clearly every way works, so $1$.

Comment: Thanks, Carry on Smiling and Brian M. Scott!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that there are $0$ checkers. This gives us $1$ arrangement.

Otherwise, let $r$ be the number of rows that contain at least one checker, and let $c$ be the number of columns that contain at least one checker. We must have $r\in\{2,3\}$ and $c\in\{2,3\}$. This gives us a few cases to consider.

If $r=2$ and $c=2$, then there are $\binom 32$ choices for the occupied rows, $\binom 32$ choices for the occupied columns, and no further choices to be made (we must place checkers at all $4$ intersections of the chosen rows and the chosen columns). So this gives us $\binom 32^2=9$ arrangements.

If $r=2$ and $c=3$, then there are $\binom 32$ choices for the occupied rows, and no further choices to be made (we must fill those rows completely). So this case gives $\binom 32=3$ arrangements.

The $r=3,c=2$ case is similar and gives us $3$ more arrangements.

Finally, if $r=3$ and $c=3$, then we can choose a set of up to 3 squares to be unoccupied, under the constraint that no two unoccupied squares are in the same row or column. There are $3!=6$ ways to have three unoccupied squares, $(9 \cdot 4)/2=18$ ways to have two unoccupied squares (first choose any square, then there are 4 choices for the second square, but divide by two because the order the squares are chosen is irrelevant), $9$ ways to have one unoccupied square, and $1$ way to have no unoccupied squares.

Totaling all these cases, we have $1+9+3+3+6+18+9+1=\boxed{50}$ arrangements.